# connect arrays into one

Tags: php, arrays, join

How i can transform this first array [ONE}: Into second array [TWO} where i can call meta_key and than i get var:  i get this array by calling specified sql rows and i am using this query:   `$user_data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE user_id = $fivesdraft->user_id ");` maybe its another better way to connect it in query? not in PHP

```
Array ONE
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [umeta_id] => 16
            [user_id] => 2
            [meta_key] => nickname
            [meta_value] => user1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [umeta_id] => 17
            [user_id] => 2
            [meta_key] => first_name
            [meta_value] => testname
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [umeta_id] => 18
            [user_id] => 2
            [meta_key] => last_name
            [meta_value] => testlastname
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [umeta_id] => 19
            [user_id] => 2
            [meta_key] => description
            [meta_value] => user desc
        )


)



Array TWO
(
    [nickname] => 'user1'
    [first_name] => 'user desc'
    [last_name] => 'user desc'
    [description] => 'user desc'
    ...

)
```

Comment: Are you using a php framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$myArray = array_reduce($arrayOne, function ($result, $item) {
    $result[$item->meta_key] = $item->meta_value;
    return $result;
}, array());
```

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over the array and write the values in a new array

```
$two = array();
foreach ($one as $item) {
    $two[$item->meta_key] = $item->meta_value;
}
```